# Computer restarts randomly - all parts A/B tested

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, bios, troubleshooting, reboot

**Brief Intro**: Computer, one fine day, started randomly restarting. No pattern seen. Occurs anywhere between 1 to 8-9 times a day, usually 2-5. Can go 2-3 days between occurrences. Restart does not involve BSOD. Event logs offer no hints. Temps aren't high - has happened during idle load. Details below, and in my first Q.

This Q follows up [Computer irregularly restarts - what should service centre look for?](https://superuser.com/q/1271153/114058)

As of now, the motherboard has just been replaced by Gigabyte. CPU has been replaced, RAM has been replaced, but the problem of random reboots continues.

Below is a crude graphical guide to the permutations in which restarts have occurred.

---

**Key**:

```
WP = Main or Wall Power source
IP = Intermediate Power Source a.k.a UPS
PSU = Computer Power Supply Unit - Corsair 550M
Cs = Computer case/cabinet
MB = Motherboard GA-H97-D3H
RAM -  RC = 2x Corsair 4GB DDR3 1333
      RK1 = 1x Kingston 8GB DDR3 1600
      RK2 = 2x Kingston 8GB DDR3 1866
CPU = i5-4440
HDDs = WD 1TB Win 7 + Seagate 2TB OpenSuSE Linux Tumbleweed
OS = within Win7 / Linux / UEFI

No add-on graphics ever (at my end), only iGPU.
```

---

These are the scenarios in which the system has been tested. FAIL at the start means restart reproduced; PASS means no restarts seen.

If there's a suffix - it indicates a changed component. Trailing `?` indicates that component may not have been present.

**In chronological order**,

```
FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU - Cs - MB - RC - CPU - HDDs - Win
FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU - Cs - MB - RC - CPU - HDDs - Linux 
FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU - Cs - MB - RC - CPU - HDDs - BIOS

--- comp sent to dealer without HDDs --->

FAIL:  WP_dlr - IP_dlr? - PSU - Cs - MB - RC - CPU - HDDs_dlr - Win_dlr
PASS:  WP_dlr - IP_dlr? - PSU_dlr - Cs_dlr - MB - RC - CPU - HDDs_dlr - Win_dlr
(^ tested for less than a day)

--- comp returned to me with dealer PSU and Cs --->

FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU_dlr - Cs_dlr - MB - RC - CPU - HDDs - Win
FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU_dlr - Cs_dlr - MB - RK1 - CPU - HDDs - Win
(^ a week passed without restarts after switching to ram RK1)
FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU_dlr - Cs_dlr - MB - RK1 - CPU - HDDs - Linux
```

contd..

```
--- comp returned to dealer without HDDs --->
--- MB only forwarded to Gigabyte --->

PASS:  WP_gb - IP_gb? - PSU_gb - Cs_gb? - MB - R_gb - CPU_gb - HDDs_gb? - ?
(^ burn-in test for 2 days)
FAIL:  WP_gb - IP_gb? - PSU_gb - Cs_gb? - MB - RC - CPU - HDDs_gb? - ?
(^ sent my CPU + Corsair RAM)

--- Gigabyte return items to dealer; say one of the RC sticks to blame --->

PASS:  WP_dlr - IP_dlr? - PSU - Cs - MB - 1xRC + RK1 - CPU - HDDs_dlr - Win_dlr
(^ tested intermittently over 3-4 days)

--- comp returned to me with "faulty" RAM removed --->

FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU - Cs - MB - 1xRC + RK1 - CPU - HDDs - Win

--- MB+CPU+RAM(RC+RK1) resent to Gigabyte --->

(no testing done; CPU examined - observed some pins have blackened; say CPU to blame)

--- dealer replaces CPU with same model --->

PASS:  WP_dlr - IP_dlr? - PSU_dlr - Cs_dlr - MB - 1xRC + RK1 - CPU_new - HDDs_dlr - Win_dlr
(^ tested for 3 days)
```

contd..

```
--- comp returned to me with new CPU --->

FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU - Cs - MB - RC + RK1 - CPU_new - HDDs - Win
FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU - Cs - MB - RC + RK1 - CPU_new - HDDs - BIOS

--- MB+CPU_new+RAM(RC+RK1) sent to Gigabyte --->

PASS:  WP_gb - IP_gb? - PSU_gb - Cs_gb? - MB - RC+RK1 - CPU_new - HDDs_gb? - ?
(^ testing setup and duration unknown but reported after 3 days; say PSU to blame)

At this stage, I call Gigabyte and explain testing history to site manager,
who offers replacement MB.

--- comp returned to me with RMAed MB --->

FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU - Cs - MB_rma - RC + RK1 - CPU_new - HDDs - Win
PASS:  WP - IP - PSU - Cs - MB_rma - RC + RK1 - CPU_new - HDDs - Linux
(^ a few hours)
FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU - Cs - MB_rma - RC + RK1 - CPU_new - HDDs - BIOS

--- swap RAM with another (working) comp, yesterday --->

FAIL:  WP - IP - PSU - Cs - MB_rma - RK2 - CPU_new - HDDs - Win
(PASS:  WP_oth - PSU_oth - Cs_oth - MB_oth - RC + RK1 - CPU_oth - HDD_oth - Win)
```

Now thinking of what my next testing step is   <sub>probably upgrading this to the theological department, but will check temporal suggestions a bit longer</sub>.

If you read the initial Q, you'll notice that the original MB was sent to Gigabyte in June. It was sent back repaired and with its BIOS upgraded to version F7. Version before was F3. The new version added support for 5th gen procs, they also prevent BIOS rollbacks. Could the new BIOS be responsible? The RMAed board has F7 as well. Against this possibility is the fact that the upgrade occurred in June and the restart behaviour started in mid-Oct.

The disappearing drive issue hasn't recurred since the first return to me from Gigabyte. No crashes during any Windows or Linux use.

I'll probably swap the PSU with the working comp, though an earlier config has been unsuccessfully tested with the dealer's PSU.

Thanks for reading. **Thoughts?**

Comment: Just the obviuos thoughts: 1) It fails when in the BIOS (or UEFI I guess). So you can ignore the OS. 2) Did you also swap SATA cables? Not that I see how that would cause a reboot in the firmeware (BIOS or UEFI), but if the OS drive disappears things might get interesting. 3) Did you try with different fans. If one of those is bad and shorts sometimes...

Comment: @Hennes 2&3) the dealer's case had different cables and fans, so yes.

Comment: How is your WP? Any possibility for low voltage? System plugged directly into a reliable wall socket? And what about the UPS? Any testing without it?

Comment: @user3169  It has been tested at two other WP sources - `wp_dlr and wp_gb`

Comment: @user3169 - there's another computer connected via another UPS and outlet in WP's room and voltage is steady at ~240 +- 5V.

Comment: Swapped UPS's? Anyway, the problem is you are trying to diagnose an intermittent problem with excessive activity. As far as I can tell, you have substituted every part but it still fails. Either something was missed or it is something else. You should replace only one part at a time and wait for it to fail (or not).

Comment: "Temps aren't high - has happened during idle load." I wouldn't trust that. Run an app that monitors the CPU temp.

Comment: I do, Speedfan - I wasn't inferring the temp from the load